# OpenGL + SDL2 Black Screen

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I'm currently learning OpenGL and have been using it with SDL2 and when trying to run a simple program I am getting a black screen. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using OpenGL 2.1 and vc compiler.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int width, height;

    width = 640;
    height = 480;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* win;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Application", 100, 100, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GLContext context;
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    height = (height <= 0) ? height = height : height = 1;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat) width / (GLfloat) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glTranslatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    SDL_Quit(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't you forgot to swap the buffers, using `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()`

Comment: That function is gone in sdl2, swapping buffers is done automatically, I think, and with `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(SDL_Window*)`

Comment: If that is the case, then you have "swapped the window" at the wrong point in your code. Move that line so it comes directly above `SDL_Delay (...)`

Answer (score 1):

The order of those is wrong:

> ```
> SDL_GLContext context;
> context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);
>
> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
> SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
> ```

The OpenGL context attributes must be set before creating the context (they are state variables, that control the context creation process).

This makes no sense: First you clear, then you swap, then you draw (into a then undefined back buffer, since the content of the back buffer is undefined after a swap) and then you *don't* swap.

> ```
> glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
> glLoadIdentity();
>
> SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
>
> glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
>
> /* this translate will move the triangle out
>  * of the NDC space i.e. it gets clipped or
>  * won't be visible at all. */
> glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
>
> glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
>   glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
> ```

This should be something like

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

glTranslatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
SDL_Delay(5000);
```

To make any sense at all. There are still loads of problems with the rest of the code, but if you change it that way, you should at least see some white triangle on a black ground.